# Is there a way to access the most recent user instruction pointer from the kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, ftrace

I am attempting to modify the Linux kernel's `user_exit` event tracepoint to give information about the code in user space that triggered it.

Unfortunately, the state of the user program is not passed into the function `context_tracking_user_enter` in `kernel/context_tracking.c`.

**Is there a way to extract the (ideally virtual) address of the last userspace instruction which ran on the current core?**

Comment: The linux oops message prints out the current PID and the threadinfo pointer. Perhaps you can check how that is implemented.